# SOLVED: making program to distill Titles and URLS from Youtube Search results

Tags: python, html, youtube

I am writing a program (code below) in Python that is a kind of directer way to go to a youtube video, avoiding the Youtube user interface.

My problems are solved, I share the code here in case anybody is interested, I managed very elegantly with Regex.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *


win=Tk() 
win.title("video search")
win.geometry('800x400') 
var = Entry(win, width=20) 
var.place(x=2,y=2)

def titlee(URL):

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
    xx=html.read().decode()
    video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", xx)
    titleee= re.findall('title\":{.*?accessibility', xx)
    title=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    URL=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for x in range(0, 6):
        print(titleee[x])
        title[x] = re.findall(':\".*?\"}',titleee[x]) 
        URL[x] = video_ids[x]
    return(URL, title)

def func():#function of the button
    x = str(var.get())
    URL = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + str(x) + "&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D"
    URL = URL.replace(" ","+")
    URL, title = titlee(URL)
    for x in range(0, 6):
        NAME = "btn" + str(x)
        globals()[NAME] = Button(win,text=title[x], width=45,height=1, anchor="w", command=(lambda t=x:func2(URL[t], title[t])))
        position = 70 + x * 40
        globals()[NAME].place(x=2,y=position)
        
def func2(URL, title):
    Func = open("GFG-1.html","w")
    Func.write("""<html>\n<head>\n<title> """ + str(title) + """
               </title>\n</head> <body><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/""" + URL + """?autoplay=1 "title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>""")              
    Func.close()
    webbrowser.open('GFG-1.html') 

btn=Button(win,text="OK", width=2,height=1,command=func)
btn.place(x=0,y=30)


mainloop()
```

Comment: *Youtube API* quiet best idea - Just in case, check your `soup` if it contains expected elements, cause site content is generated dynamically by `JavaScript`.

Comment: I seem to have found the solution of my question from another, somewhat unrelated post. Just these Lines of code:

clip = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + str(URL))
    inspect = BeautifulSoup(clip.content, "html.parser")
    yt_title = inspect.find_all("meta", property="og:title")
    print(yt_title)

Comment: @WillemvanHouten I'm glad you found the solution. Can you please post your answer and accept it? - see [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you.